# PLS-00103 : pl/sql error

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

i tried to include two begin-end block in a plsql code.But it gave me a pls-00103 code.i checked that all character are in DBC case.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax you have used : `BEGIN label COMMAND ..... END label` is wrong.

---

Refer to the documentation of [PL/SQL block](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/block.htm#LNPLS01303)

---

**plsql_block ::= [ << label >> ] [ DECLARE declare_section ]  body**

[image]

PL/SQL block may start with optional **label** name which must be surrounded by double **<<** and **>>**, then optional **declare section**, then obligatory **body** section.

---

**body ::= BEGIN statement; [statement; ....] [EXCEPTION exception_handler] END [ name] ;**
[image]

In turn body section must contain **BEGIN** statement, then one or more  **statement** (at last one is obligatory), then optional exception block, then obligatory **END** statement, then optional **name** (label) without any << or >>, then obligatory semicolon **;**

---

So your code (if you want to use labels/names) must look like this:

```
<<a>> BEGIN
   commit;
END a;
/

<<b>> 
BEGIN
   commit;
END b;
/
```